# Scale_Cuda or Scale_npp no such filter found error

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, nvidia

I, I have been trying to use hardware transcoding using nvidia GPU, everything works fine but when I use scale filters such as scale_cuda or scale_npp, I get an error no such filter.
I have tried compiling the ffmpeg using the compilation guide also tried one provided on Nvidia site it still does not work, even after using those complied version I still get an error saying No such filters. Is there anyway I can enable those filters. If I use resize filter this works but it stretch vertical videos, and using scale filter from ffmpeg consumes more of CPU and its not efficient. Could anyone help on this please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When compiling FFmpeg from source, have you added the `--enable-cuda-nvcc` option for the `./configure` script? Note that the CUDA SDK must be installed.

Comment: for scale_cuda you need https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/euiwtv/scale_cuda_vs_scale_npp/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into probably the same problem, see the error message below.

What fixed it for me was adding `hwupload_cuda` to the `-vf` statement, eg.

- from `-vf "scale_cuda=-2:720:format=yuv420p"` (error)
- to `-vf "hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=-2:720:format=yuv420p"` (working).

I hope this helps.
Just in case, here the complete command: `ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input-1080p.mp4" -map 0 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset p7 -tune hq -b:v 2.5M -maxrate 8M -vf "hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=-2:720:format=yuv420p" -c:a copy -c:s copy  "output-720p.mp4"`

...As for the error message I got (using the precompiled executables from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/), full git build version: 2023-07-19-git-efa6cec759), here it is:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vf#0:0 @ 00000xxxxx00000] Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Function not implemented
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Another working option is to use `-hwaccel nvdec` _without_ the `hwupload_cuda` option, e.g.:
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input-1080p.mp4" -map 0 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset p7 -tune hq -b:v 2.5M -maxrate 8M -vf "scale_cuda=-2:720:format=yuv420p" -c:a copy -c:s copy  "output-720p.mp4"`
But this runs at only about 240 fps instead of 280 fps compared to the previous command (on a RTX 2060 (Laptop))